# I cant seem to insert into the database the value of my select tag

Tags: php

I'm editing something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="type">
        <option>Default</option>
        <option>Training Center</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

What I want to do is select the option I wanted and update that into a database column...

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');

 $idselect = $db->query("SELECT max(id) FROM users");
$id = $db->query($idselect,'id');

$connect = $db->query("UPDATE users SET userType='".$_POST['type']."' Where id = '$id'");
```

But my problem is it still wont show in the database. 
Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong??

also the userType column I'm updating has a code like this

```
$userType = 'default';
```

Comment: Let's start with the HTML, your `<option>`'s don't have any values assigned to them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011735/insert-value-of-html-select-form-into-mysql-database

Comment: @Daan Value is optional not mandatory. So your comment doesn't provide a solution check this: [link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option#HTML_Attributes) 

- value = string
Provides a value for element.
If there isn't, the value of an option element is the textContent of the element.

Comment: @OsamaSayed I know, I find it a bad habbit though.

Comment: @Daan Yeah it gets clearer when 'value' is present but just saying that It doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Can you echo the value of `$_POST['type']`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use value attribute in select tag

```
 <select name="type">
    <option value="Default">Default</option>
    <option value="Training Center">Training Center</option>
</select>
```